# Como salvar relatório FastReport em PDF em modo silencioso?

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Eu consigo gerar o PDF a partir do código abaixo:

```
fdm.frxPDFExport.FileName := 'C:\PASTA_TESTE\ARQUIVO_TESTE.PDF';
frxReport.PrepareReport();
frxReport.Export(fdm.frxPDFExport);
```

O detalhe é que ele me mostra a tela para escolher onde salvar o arquivo.

Eu gostaria de salvar sem intervenção do usuário, já que determinei o caminho e nome do arquivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altere a propriedade `FileName` e `DefaultPath` para o que você precisa no export.

Também altere `frxrRelatorio.PrintOptions.ShowDialog := False;` para não exibir a caixa de dialog

Comment: Olá Gabriel, obrigado pela resposta, além do PrintOptions = False, também coloquei fdm.frxPDFExport.ShowDialog := False; e deu certo.

Comment: Isso, eu me esqueci desse o outro era para a impressão, esse era para o export